# How to Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7-x64, windows-phone-8

I have all my workspace and everything set up on Windows 7 but I also want to develop Windows Phone 8 but as stated on Microsoft website that It can not be installed on Windows 7.

Do anybody knows how to install in on Windows 7. I have found a crack but I don't know how to run this. You can get this from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14833950/Softwares/WP8-SDK-9900-MSI-Install-Windows7.zip)
Please tell me if anybody knows how to install it. here is a link to [WP 8 ISO file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257234&clcid=0x409)

> Edit:

There could be several reasons to install WP 8 in Windows 7. Like I have purchased a Wndows 7 recently and I don't want to make shift to Windows 8 right now, because I don't feel comfortable with its UI. Its more for a tablet or touch screen PC.

I have set-up all my workspace and other projects on Windows 7, I don't want to waste my time in setting up on Windows 8, I don't even know that how they gona perform on Windows 8. So there are so many genuine reasons.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can install it by first extracting all the files from the ISO and then overwriting those files with the files from the ZIP. Then you can run the batch file as administrator to do the installation. Most of the packages install on windows 7, but I haven't tested yet how well they work.

Comment: yeah but Emptor needs Virtualization that is absent in Windows 7. but on one can stop you to run it on your phone. Means you can develop windows 8 apps on windows 7 but not emulator :)

Comment: @AZ_ Were you successful in running Windows Phone 8 Emulator on Windows 7? I don't have windows phone.

Comment: Yeah I was successful, there was a small problem. I don't remember but Now I have shifted to Windows 8.1. It's better to switch your OS.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a link from developer.nokia.com wiki pages, which explains how to install [Windows Phone 8 SDK on a Virtual Machine with Working Emulator](http://www.developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator)

And another link [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_Emulator_in_a_Windows_8_VHD)

AFAIK, it is not possible to directly install WP8 SDK in Windows 7, because WP8 sdk is VS 2012 supported and also its emulator works on a Hyper-V (which is integrated into the Windows 8).

Comment: these links seem to be broken now that Microsoft has acquired Nokia :(

Comment: Fixed the broken links @Lucas!!

Comment: @nkchandra links seems like broken again, can you check or answer my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506496/phonegap-windows-mobile-app-emulator if possible?