# Is it possible to develop Windows Phone 8 applications using the WP8 SDK on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

Is there any work around so developers who does not have Windows 8 can develop for windows phone using Windows Phone SDK 8.0?

Comment: @BlackHatShadow Windows 7

Comment: isn't that "Operating System"? sorry I don't get the question.

Comment: yes it is but it's the same i suggest for the TS :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7)

Comment: I think there's a Way:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to develop for Windows Phone 8 on Windows 7. In the system requirements of Windows Phone 8 SDK it states you need to have Windows 8 to develop Windows Phone 8 apps.

Directly from MSDN:

> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 requires 64-bit Windows 8 Pro or higher. You **can't** develop Windows Phone 8 apps **on Windows 7**, on **Windows Server 2008**, or on **Windows Server 2012**. The Windows Phone 8 Emulator has special hardware, software, and configuration requirements. For more info, see [System requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

This is mainly because of the Hyper-V emulator that is in windows 8. **Be sure if you buy Windows 8 you get the Pro (64bits) version** because the normal version has no Hyper-V in it also your BIOS has to support virtualization to run the emulator in Hyper-V.

Comment: The hyper-V requirement is for the emulator so you can still develop windows phone 8 app without it if you test directly on a phone

Comment: I think it will not install if you try to run it on Windows 7