# WP Development Registration fails with Nokia 822

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone-8, zune

So I recently got a Nokia 822 and a windows development account and was trying to register my device using windows 7 and I continually get the message:

> Unable to connect to phone.  Please check that the Zune software is
>   running and that Zune's sync parnership with your phone has been
>   established.

I installed the Zune software, and reinstalled it as suggested by the microsoft site, I also restarted the phone and my PC several times as well as using the USB cord that came with the device in multiple ports on my PC.  I can see the phone from my file explorer, and I am able to connect to it with the WindowsPhone.exe program, however whenever I try to register my phone for development I always get the message above.  Anything I am missing here to be able to register my phone for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nokia 822 is Windows Phone 8, so Zune is no longer used. Instead you need to use the [Windows Phone SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=259416) 7.8 (Windows 7) or 8.0 (Windows 8 only) to register it. There are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7) to get the 8.0 SDK running on Windows 7, but the emulator will not run.

Here are the steps [provided by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

1. Turn on your phone and unlock the phone screen.
2. On your phone, ensure that the date and time are correct.
3. Connect your phone to your computer by using the USB cable that came with your phone.
4. On your computer’s Start screen, switch to All apps view.
5. Under Windows Phone SDK (7.8/8.0), click Windows Phone Developer Registration.
6. Verify that the Status message displays Identified Windows Phone 8 device. Click the Register button to unlock the phone. If your phone is already registered, the Status message indicates this and you see an Unregister button.
7. Click Register.
8. In the Sign In dialog box for your Microsoft account (formerly known as a Windows Live ID), enter the Microsoft account and password that correspond to your Dev Center membership. Click Sign In.
9. After your phone is successfully registered, the Status message displays *Congratulations! You have successfully unlocked your Windows Phone*.

Comment: I can't download the windows 8.0 SDK while using windows 7, does this mean I can't develop on the phone?

Comment: Sorry, have updated the answer about Win 7/8. What version of the SDK are you using? How are you trying to register it?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia As far as I know you can use Windows Phone SDK 8 only in Windows 8.