# xamarin.forms with VS 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I start learning the Xamarin with the latest of VS 2015 (enterprise)
I create a a cross platform project with the 'blank xml app'

[image: xaml template]

I got a solution with 5 projects created: portable, droid, ios, UWP and windows 8.1. All of them cannot get compiled at all, since the "initializecomponent" missing

[image: InitializeComponent Missing]

After I've updated the package Xamarin.forms to the latest version, almost of them can be compiled without any errors, except the windows 8.1. I tried around but got no luck, please advise which packages I need to install to?

[image]

Edited: add an image "cannot install the package xamarin.forms for the two.windows"
[image]

Comment: Has i understand, you can compile every project except the w8.1, correct?

Comment: yes, after upgrade the package xamarin.forms. Just get the errors with windows 8.1

Comment: as in the figure I attached, I don't see the project w8.1 has any dll referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to right-click the **Two.Windows** project -> click **Manage NuGet Packages** -> in the **Installed packages** tab, if `Xamarin.Forms` is listed, uninstall it -> Now click on the **Online** tab -> search for and install `Xamarin.Forms` only in your **Two.Windows** project

After that, I would completely close Visual Studio, click save if asked, delete all files and folders in each project folder's `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders, reopen the solution and rebuild the **Two.Windows** project.

If you still have issues after that let us know and also post a new image of the references listed under your **Two.Windows** project.

Edit: Here is a list of references that I see in my default **Windows 8.1** project:

- .NET for Windows Store app

  - Identity: .NETCore,Version=v4.5.1
  - Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\
- Windows 8.1

  - Identity: Windows,Version=8.1
  - Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\
- Xamarin.Forms.Core
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Tablet
- Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

The I also have the reference to my shared project in there as well as Newtonsoft.Json, but I am not sure if that came by default or not.

Edit #2: Now that we know you are on Windows 7, we know why the Windows Phone 8.1 project is failing. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904068/3850012) answer for more information but the short of it is that you cannot install the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK on Windows 7 nor can you deploy WP 8.1 apps using Windows 7. The answer also gives some alternatives you might be able to use. I think the upgrade is free from what I remember.

Comment: hi, cannot install the package xamarin.forms into the project two.windows, I edited my question to attach an image at last, thank you.

Comment: @khoailang you might want to try right-clicking you solution and uninstalling and then reinstalling Xamarin Forms in all of the projects that need it. Not sure why it would error out like that. The project I currently have shows the `Xamarin.Forms` package happily sitting in the `Windows` project.

Comment: I am not sure why either, I have all kind of stuff has just installed fresh, just create new a project, have not yet modify any single line ... at the very first time projects created, no one can be compiled, I did removed the old package and install the latest version, some of them now work just the windows 8.1 doesn't

Comment: can you please help to list out which dlls need to refer to? and where to get them, I can try to add manually myself

Comment: @khoailang That really should not be necessary but I added the list of default references that I see in my **Window 8.1** project

Comment: thank you, I tried to have the VS 2015 installed in the Windows 10, everything is working just fine. As in the spec, the UWP just is supported in the Windows 10, but I am not sure if we need to have windows 8 installed for the "window 8.1" and "windows phone 8.1" project, is it?

Comment: @khoailang No you do not need Windows 8.1 to run Windows Phone 8.1 projects. Could you try creating a brand new solution and seeing if the project works for you?

Comment: That is what I tried first, I always create a project solution, I even uninstalled and reinstalled the visual studio , my colleagues also got the same errors. We are using win 7 enterprise .

Comment: @khoailang Ahh! Thats the issue. See Edit #2 in my answer.

Comment: @khoailang No problem, glad we got to the bottom of it!