# How to register windows phone8 with windows phone7 sdk?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a windows 7 PC and i want to develop windows phone 7 apps. So i have installed windows phone 7 SDK, everything is working fine.

But i have a windows phone 8 physical device. So to debug my apps with my windows phone 8 physical device, i have to register my phone with "Windows Phone Developer Registration".

my problem is: i have a windows phone 7 SDK and windows phone 8 device. but i could not able to register my windows phone 8 with windows phone 7 SDK.

Any body encountered with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, directly, however there is a few hacks to install Windows Phone 8 sdk on a Windows 7 computer. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7) article. You can't register or deploy on Windows Phone 8 device without Windows Phone SDK 8.

Comment: okay. can i register my windows phone 8 mobile in my friends system where he has windows phone 8 SDK and use the same device in my windows 7 system/PC to debug or deploy an app targeted for windows phone 7?

Comment: No, Windows Phone 8 uses different scheme to connect. Windows Phone 7 uses Zune, Windows Phone 8 connects directly. Windows Phone 7 SDK doesn't know that. Install Windows Phone 8 sdk on your Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows 8 and install windows phone 8 sdk.With this you can make apps for windows phone 7.5 and windows phone 8 both.

Comment: yes true. but i have windows 7 PC with me and don't want to upgrade to windows 8 in near future. So looking for alternatives to develop apps targeted for windows phone 7.