# Is there any Windows Phone website emulator/screenshotter?

Tags: cross-browser, windows-phone-8-emulator, webpage-screenshot, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm using Browsershots, BrowserStack and Sauce Labs to test websites in different browsers. But none of these provides Windows Phone emulator. Is there any online (both free or paid) website, which provides the Windows Phone emulator for testing websites?

And if not: is there any other Windows Phone emulator for Windows than the Visual Studio native emulator?

I googled a lot, but there was nothing. Totally nothing, just only the Microsoft's Windows Phone SDK for Visual Studio, which includes the emulator. But it works only for Windows 8 and I have WIndows 7 on my PC.

Comment: Yeah, it's really annoying that they made the emulator Windows 8 only. :s

Comment: Apparently there's a hack/crack to make it run on Windows 7. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7  -edit- On second reading, it seems to be about the SDK in general, but it seems the emulator is still not working after that.

Comment: Also, I don't know of any third party emulator. I think you're out of luck, unless you get a virtual machine running as described in the other answer to the question I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use just the browser, you can use the latest IE, open it up and press F12,
then click on the bottom icon and you will see a screen like this one :
[image: Emulate Wp IE]

That's pretty much the only other way to emulate WP 8 IE.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know, that IE has the built-in emulator. Thank you