# Windows phone Application development

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i would be developing windows phone app that would fit into windows phone 8 OS. I have a laptop which has windows 7 OS. Now the question is should i have to upgrade to windows 8 or is there a workaround?

Current Laptop - Windows 7 OS,64 bit, 4GB RAM

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7)

Comment: And see also: http://forums.wpcentral.com/software-development-hacking/257343-tut-install-full-wp8-sdk-windows-7-a.html

Comment: ['Officially' it's impossible, though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402529(v=vs.105).aspx), so since you are having a hard time finding all this information (which was just a simple Google query away), you will definitely have a hard time to do the necessary hacking to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To run the Windows Phone 8.x SDK on your PC, you'll have to upgrade to Windows 8. If you're looking to get started with the latest 8.1 SDK, you'll need the Windows 8.1 update with [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).

To run the emulators, you'll need to have Hyper-V active on your machine as it is required. If your machine doesn't support Hyper-V, the only options are to upgrade your device or run a Virtual Machine hosted in the cloud. [Microsoft Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) provide great hosting for developer VMs at a relatively cheap cost.

The other option is to buy a Windows Phone 8 device as you don't require Hyper-V to debug your applications straight to a device. At the cost of some mid-range device, you'd be better actually getting a device.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Finally i decided to buy a new machine "Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series (AMD)". Just need help on the following.processor -"AMD E1-6010 APU with Radeon™ R2 Graphics". OS - Windows 8.1 Single Language (64Bit) . RAM - 4GB. Does this Machine Have SLAT capability? can i develop windows phone 8.1 apps using this machine and use windows phone 8.1 emulators or i need to have windows 8.1 pro version of os?