# Coded UI for Windows Mobile application testing

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate in my Windows 7 machine. How to start with automation testing of Windows Phone application? While creating new project I am not finding ***Store Apps->Windows Apps*** option in my New Project creation window.

Comment: Also make sure you have visual studio enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a windows phone SDK.Check this post for more help:
[How to Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7)