# Running emualtor from with VM Ware

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, virtualization, windows-phone-8-emulator, vmware-workstation

My PC OS is Windows 7.

I have installed VM Ware

I have installed Windows 8 Standard in VM Ware

I am trying to create a Windows Phone 8 app.

I want to use the PCs internet connection rather than the GPRS on my mobile.

I have recently found out I need to run the phone emulators to do this.

But, the emulators do not work because I am launching under VM Ware.

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Why don't you run emulator under your machines primary OS?

Comment: because Windows phone 8 cannot be developed in Windows 7

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also running Emulator(VM) within a VM is not supported.

Comment: Not supported but is possible. Have found a fix from link above