# How to install WINDOWS SDK 8 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, sdk

I have downloaded the installation at this link [link windows sdk 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx). But once installed, the following error message

"the installer encountered an unexpected error installing this package. this may indicate a problem with this package. the error code is 2753".

How can I fix this bug? Who can help me to install win sdk 8 on win 7?

Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7)

Comment: I mean windows sdk (sotfwave development kit) not windows phone :D. tks

Answer (score 0):

Its not posibal to install WINDOWS SDK 8 on Windows 7 . Thw apis ,XML layout system and other lots of new features used in WINDOWS 8 or above are not supported in Windows 7

you can find difference on we bit twin WINDOWS 8 on Windows 7 on web like [this](http://digitalunite.com/guides/computer-basics/windows-8/what-are-differences-between-windows-7-and-windows-8)

Comment: I am a programmer and i need environment to be able to code. As far as I know, the windows can support this, but I can not.