# Developing Windows Phone App on Windows 7 OS

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-7

I'm developing a windows phone app. I'm using Windows 7 OS.
Which Visual Studio version should I use and also which Windows App version should I target?
Can it be WP7.1?
And also, I would need to use WebView. Is WebView available in 7.1? Or is there any other alternative of WebView in WP7.1?

I've gone through many articles but still unable to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not to develop against the Windows Phone 7.1 API. It's outdated for more than three years now. You can generally install the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK on a Windows 7 system: [How to Install Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7)

The results will satisfy you and your users more than a Windows Phone 7 app.

The mobile app market turns really fast. Much faster than the desktop application market. You should consider to do the free update to Windows 10 in order to be able to create Windows Phone 8.1 apps. Windows 10 Mobile is about to come this year. It supports the [Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) so developers only need to develop an app onnce and run it on desktop PCs, phones and other Windows 10 devices. If I started a new app now I'd definitely create a UWP app. 
Don't waste your time developing apps against an outdated API. Maybe you can still develop Windows Phone 7 apps now. But you'll probably don't get them into the stores in the future. It's just a matter of time when Microsoft stops developers to publish these old apps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So, should it be perfect if I target Windows Phone App 8.1 and install Windows 8.1 OS?

Comment: That sounds good. But I prefer to install Windows 10. Consider targeting Universal Windows Platform. Windows 10 Mobile is on the way.