# Phonegap - Windows mobile app emulator

Tags: phonegap-build, windows-phone-8-emulator

As per the phone gap documentation I had added the ripple google chrome extension to test Phonegap - windows emulator. But it does not have any option to check windows OS emulator.

How can I setup Phonegap - Windows emulator?

Since publishing windows app is taking too long time unable to launch app every time and test.

Can anyone help me to setup a Windows emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

Phonegap provides the solution for this. We can download the `phonegap Developer` Application from android and windows market place.

Android: [Click Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app)

Windows: [Click Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/phonegap-developer/9wzdncrdfsj0)

Once installation done, get the URL and connect through developer tool. Below is the reference screenshot.

[image]